# How would I connect this signal to the slot

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to create a signal in my main class `foo` so that a static method in a different class could emit it.I just started of with QT so I am a bit confused. I currently have the following code

```
class Foo : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Foo(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~Foo();
signals:
    void UpdateSignal(int val);
private slots:
    void MySlot(int val);
};

Foo::Foo(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags): QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    //How do I connect Bfoo::somemethod() here.  I know its suppose to be like
    connect(xx,SIGNAL(UpdateSignal(int)),this, SLOT(MySlot(int)));
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

void Foo::MySlot(int val)
{
 //Do something..
}

Now I have this class

Class Bfoo
{
   static void somemethod()
   {
       emit UpdateSignal(12);
   }
}
```

Any suggestions on how the static `somemethod()` could emit the `UpdateSignal`

Answer (score 2):

When you emit signal it is necessary to know which object is emitting it. This is because signals are not implemented to be messages between different classes but messages between **instances** of (possibly different) classes.
Secondly, signals are protected methods. They are not accessible for external users. What you can do is define public method in `Foo` which will do the emission:

```
void Foo:EmitUpdateSignal(int x) {
    emit UpdateSignal(x);
}
```

And then in your `Bfoo::somemethod()` you need to pass object which will emit signal:

```
void BFoo::somemethod(Foo &f) {
    f.EmitUpdateSignal(12);
}
```

However, notice what you are doing. You emit signal which is connected to the slot in the same instance. This suggests design flaw but I cannot give any hints without more details about what are you going to achieve.

Comment: Thanks but this seems like a hack. Are static methods even allowed to call signals ?

Comment: To emit object you need instance of it. So static method cannot emit signal which is member of its class, because there is no object. But it can emit signals the way I showed you.